# Is it possible to pipe into dirsplit?

Tags: files, pipe

I'm trying to figure out the "Linux way" of accomplishing the following task. I have a directory with a bunch of sub-directories, each of which contain multiple files of various filetypes. I can easily narrow that down using the "find" command:

```
find . -name "*.jpg"
```

Which would return me a list of all of the files ending in .jpg. In addition (but separately), I can also split a directory into groups of files, 100MB each, with the dirsplit command:

```
dirsplit --size 100MB -m --expmode 1 .
```

So, now two questions. First, I'd like to combine the two commands, so that dirsplit acts only on the output of the 'find' command - i.e. it only rearranges those JPG's, instead of rearranging everything. Is it possible to pipe into dirsplit?

The second question is the "-m" flag, which you can see here: https://manned.org/dirsplit/15f31c9a will cause dirsplit to actually move the files to the desired folders. My question is whether it's possible to copy instead of move - meaning, leave the files where they are but make an additional copy of them in groups of 100.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dirsplit -H` will give you some more info on the command, including an example of using it with find.

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -printf "%s %p" | dirsplit -T- --size 100MB --expmode 1 -L
```

`-T-` reads filelist from stdin in the form "*filename filesize*"

`-L` creates hard links (it seems there is no copy option)

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!